# XML Structure breaking feed producing error document is empty

Tags: php, xml, rss, feed

I would like some guidance, please. I have been trying to implement an XML structure, then it gets parsed through PHP to get the final result. This system wasn't set by me but someone else, so I am bit lost.

The structure seems fine until these two tags are added

```
  <videoItems> <videoItem>  </videoItem>  </videoItems>
```

then I am getting the error: "This page contains the following errors: error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error." If I remove these tags, the feed worsk fine, parses through PHP just fine.

This is the structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:msn="http://microsoft.com/msnrss" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
<channel><source>Media</source><description>Video feed</description>
<item>
<title>***headline***</title>
<videoItems>
<videoItem>
<media:content url="***videoURL***" type="video/mp4"></media:content>
<videoFiletype>video/mp4</videoFiletype>
<videoDesc>***abstract***</videoDesc>
<videoLang>EN</videoLang>
<videoCover> <media:thumbnail height="650" width="1000" type="image/jpeg" url="***img1***"/></videoCover>
<media:keywords>
<![CDATA[ ***people*** ]]>
</media:keywords>
<videoTags>
<tag>***people***,***location***,***brands***</tag>
</videoTags>
</videoItem>
</videoItems>
<pubDate>***story_publish_ISO***</pubDate>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

This is the part of PHP which parses the MRSS:

```
                      case 'mrss':

                        foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
                            $vidFile = $item->vurl;

                            $vidFilename = $this->rootPath . '/' . $target->filePath . '/' . $vidFile;

                            if ($this->devMode == true) {
                                $fileExists = true;
                                $item->vidfs = 12345;
                            } else {
                                $fileExists = file_exists($vidFilename);
                                if (!$fileExists) {
                                    $this->saveFile($this->sourceHost . '/' . $item->vurl, $vidFilename);
                                    $fileExists = file_exists($vidFilename);

                                    if ($fileExists)
                                        $item->vidfs = filesize($vidFilename);
                                }
                            }

                            if ($fileExists) {
                                $item->vidfn = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $target->fileUrlRoot . '/' . $vidFile;
                                $data = str_replace($item->find, $item->vidfn, $data);

                            } else {
                                $this->errors[] = 'Missing Video ' . $vidFile;
                            }
                        }

                        if (isset($target->processContent)) {
                            $pc = $target->processContent;
                            $data = $pc($data);
                        }

                        $this->setContent($data);

                        break;
                    default:
                        if ($this->debug)
                            $this->debugging[] = 'Items Processing for ' . $details->expected . " is missing";

                        $this->errors[] = 'Items Processing is not configured';
                }

                return true;

            } else {
                $this->errors[] = 'Could not find any feed Items';
```

I have tried changing the header-type but it doesn't make any difference either. 
I would appreciate some help.